# TinyMCE SCRIPT5: Access is denied. Typical cross-domain error on same domain

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using TinyMCE load via AJAX but on the same domain, same protocol (https), and it works fine on any other Browser. I feel like IE thinks I'm crossing domains although I'm certainly not.
The project is hosted at Media Temple (gs), it was working fine on my (dv) and doesn't seem to work since I transferred, activated the SSL, etc...

Edit : I'm using the latest version of TinyMCE (3.5b2).

Edit 2 : My guess is :
*The problem isn't from TinyMCE itself since the same exact script works on our own intranet (with any browser, IE included.) I think the browser thinks we are "cross-domaining" although we are not.* My guess would be a htaccess problem or something related to root folders...

Edit 3 : Do not use document.domain = "domain.com" on your JS if you are not cross-domaining.

Problem solved.

Comment: Interestingly enough, this just came up in my bugtracker for the exact same thing.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.devicemedia.ca/tinymce-vs-internet-explorer-9-ie9-problem-solved/

Comment: @cillosis you should add that as an answer!

Comment: The problem isn't from TinyMCE itself IMHO because the exact same version was working on another server. It is unbelievable. I can actually make this exact same script work perfectly on another server. Thanks for sharing though.

Comment: @melee I don't know if it will correct the problem. Just sharing some information I came across in trying to find a solution.

Comment: this works for me on Internet Explorer 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use

```
document.domain = "domain.com"
```

on your JS header if you are not cross-domaining. It seemed to have solved all my issues.